# Asp.net request.querystring

Tags: asp.net

I am using `request.querystring` just to access a parameter which I am passing from one page to other.

It is giving me an error.

> Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString' cannot be
>   used like a method.

I am using C#.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It sounds like you're writing:

```
Request.QueryString("Param");
```

When you want:

```
Request.QueryString["Param"];
```

Note the square brackets.

Comment: I did this and get an error `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.`